# Solve integral example

Tags: integration

How to solve $\int \frac{1}{x^3(1+x)} dx$ I try to solve with partial fraction method but don't get answer.
$\frac{1}{x^3(1+x)}=\frac{A}{x^3}+\frac{B}{(1+x)} $

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x^3(1+x)} \neq \frac{A}{x^3} + \frac{B}{1+x}$$

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x^3(1+x)}=\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^3}+\frac{D}{1+x}$$ is the correct approach.

Comment: Hint: Try
$$
\frac{1}{x^3(1+x)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x^3}+\frac{D}{(1+x)}
$$

Comment: Write $$1=x^3+1-x^3$$

Answer (score 3):

Keep re-writing $1$ as $(1+x)-x$. You will get:
$$ \frac{1}{x^3(1+x)} = \frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2(1+x)} = \frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x(1+x)} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1+x}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Because of the $x^3$, which is basically the root $x=0$ repeated 3 times, the partial fraction decomposition would actually be:
$$ \frac{1}{x^3(1+x)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{C}{x^3} + \frac{D}{1+x} $$

Let me know if you require further assistance.